# Can I subset an aggregated CellDataSet object using Monocle in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a CelldataSet object (cds):

```
> class(cds)
[1] "CellDataSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "monocle"
```

composed of 6 different aggregated samples that can be distinguished by the suffixes of their barcodes. Here is a sample of what these look like:

```
cds$barcode
1   ACCAACGACTTGCC-1
2   CGCACTACTCGATG-4
3   CGTACAGAGTATCG-5
4   CGTCAAGATCACCC-5
5   ACTGAGACCCGTAA-2
6   TTAGACCTCGGGAA-6
7   TTCAAGCTGGTATC-3
8   TTTGACTGTCCTTA-4
9   TTTGCATGCTCTTA-4
10  AAACATTGAAGCCT-5
```

Is it possible to split this CellDataSet object into 6 smaller CellDataSet objects that each comprise  barcodes with the same "-n" suffix, so I can analyse each sample separately? For example, the barcodes of CellDataSet1 would look like:

```
cds$barcode
1   AAACCGTGCCCTCA-1
2   AAACGCACACGCAT-1
3   AAACGGCTTCCGAA-1
4   AAAGACGAACCCAA-1
5   AAAGACGACTGTTT-1
6   AAAGAGACAAAGCA-1
7   AAAGATCTGGTAAA-1
8   AAAGCAGAGCAAGG-1
9   AAAGCAGATTATCC-1
10  AAAGCCTGATGACC-1
```

etc, and would contain the corresponding attributes as in the original object.

Many thanks!

Abigail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tidyverse to solve the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataseti <- data.frame(barcode = c("ACCAACGACTTGCC-1",
                                  "GCACTACTCGATG-4",
                                  "CGTACAGAGTATCG-5",
                                  "CGTCAAGATCACCC-5",
                                  "ACTGAGACCCGTAA-2",
                                  "TTAGACCTCGGGAA-6", 
                                  "TTCAAGCTGGTATC-3",
                                  "TTTGACTGTCCTTA-4",
                                  "TTTGCATGCTCTTA-4",
                                  "AAACATTGAAGCCT-5"),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Let's say you want group 4

```
dataseti %>% separate(barcode, c("chain","group"),"-") %>% filter(group == 4)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Manu! Is there a way of doing this without creating a data frame? I have edited my question to include the class of the cds. I would also like to retain all the data relating to the barcodes of each group.